# Zimbra Desktop 7.2.5 issues configuration

Tags: java, soap, zimbra, zimlet

After installing Zimbra desktop 7_2_5 with success  and during configuration account I encountered this problem.

> Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect
>
> Afficher les détails de l'erreur
>   com.zimbra.common.soap.SoapFaultException: Invalid credentials
>   ExceptionId:com.zimbra.cs.offline.ab.gab.GDataServiceException:
>   Invalid credentials
>   ExceptionId:btpool0-9:1425653744332:a7aee7d352d51494
>   Code:gdata.INVALID_CREDENTIALS at
>   com.zimbra.cs.offline.ab.gab.GDataServiceException.doFailures(GDataServiceException.java:70)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.cs.account.offline.OfflineProvisioning.testDataSource(OfflineProvisioning.java:757)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.cs.account.offline.OfflineProvisioning.createDataSourceAccount(OfflineProvisioning.java:835)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.cs.account.offline.OfflineProvisioning.createAccount(OfflineProvisioning.java:641)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.cs.service.admin.CreateAccount.handle(CreateAccount.java:64)
>   at com.zimbra.soap.SoapEngine.dispatchRequest(SoapEngine.java:412) at
>   com.zimbra.soap.SoapEngine.dispatch(SoapEngine.java:287) at
>   com.zimbra.soap.SoapEngine.dispatch(SoapEngine.java:158) at
>   com.zimbra.soap.SoapServlet.doWork(SoapServlet.java:303) at
>   com.zimbra.soap.SoapServlet.doPost(SoapServlet.java:217) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) at
>   com.zimbra.cs.servlet.ZimbraServlet.service(ZimbraServlet.java:206) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:218)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:422)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.rewrite.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:230)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:585)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:988)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:415) at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:429)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:451)
>   Caused by:
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$InvalidCredentialsException:
>   Invalid credentials at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:586)
>   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:490)
>   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:336)
>   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:362)
>   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:317)
>   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:301)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.cs.offline.ab.gab.GabService.authenticate(GabService.java:66)
>   at com.zimbra.cs.offline.ab.gab.GabService.(GabService.java:61) at
>   com.zimbra.cs.offline.ab.gab.SyncSession.(SyncSession.java:96) at
>   com.zimbra.cs.offline.ab.gab.GabImport.test(GabImport.java:42) at
>   com.zimbra.cs.offline.OfflineImport.test(OfflineImport.java:95) at
>   com.zimbra.cs.offline.GMailImport.test(GMailImport.java:41) at
>   com.zimbra.cs.datasource.DataSourceManager.test(DataSourceManager.java:209)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.cs.account.offline.OfflineProvisioning.testDataSource(OfflineProvisioning.java:745)
>   ... 30 more Code:gdata.INVALID_CREDENTIALS at
>   com.zimbra.common.soap.Soap12Protocol.soapFault(Soap12Protocol.java:88)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.common.soap.SoapTransport.extractBodyElement(SoapTransport.java:354)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.common.soap.SoapTransport.parseSoapResponse(SoapTransport.java:313)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.common.soap.SoapHttpTransport.invoke(SoapHttpTransport.java:260)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.common.soap.SoapHttpTransport.invoke(SoapHttpTransport.java:164)
>   at com.zimbra.common.soap.SoapTransport.invoke(SoapTransport.java:407)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.common.soap.SoapTransport.invokeWithoutSession(SoapTransport.java:393)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.cs.account.soap.SoapProvisioning.invokeRequest(SoapProvisioning.java:342)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.cs.account.soap.SoapProvisioning.invoke(SoapProvisioning.java:350)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.cs.account.soap.SoapProvisioning.createAccount(SoapProvisioning.java:493)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.cs.offline.jsp.JspProvStub.createOfflineDataSource(JspProvStub.java:126)
>   at com.zimbra.cs.offline.jsp.XmailBean.doRequest(XmailBean.java:262)
>   at com.zimbra.cs.offline.jsp.GmailBean.doRequest(GmailBean.java:42) at
>   com.zimbra.cs.offline.jsp.FormBean.doRequest(FormBean.java:156) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstFunction.getValue(AstFunction.java:127) at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.evaluateExpression(PageContextImpl.java:1001)
>   at org.apache.jsp.desktop.accsetup_jsp._jspx_meth_c_when_0(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.jsp.desktop.accsetup_jsp._jspx_meth_c_choose_0(Unknown
>   Source) at org.apache.jsp.desktop.accsetup_jsp._jspService(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:389)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) at
>   com.zimbra.webClient.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:64) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.cs.servlet.SetHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHeaderFilter.java:79)
>   at
>   com.zimbra.webClient.filters.SetHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHeaderFilter.java:239)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:218)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:422)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.rewrite.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:230)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:585)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:988)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:415) at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:429)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:451)

Comment: You've probably configured it with the wrong credentials. Or that is what your stacktrace suggests.

Comment: I formatted the error code.

Answer (score 0):

the Log is telling us the next - INVALID_CREDENTIALS
What Zimbra Server do you have? Or what kind of account are your trying to configure?

Also in which OS did you install Zimbra Desktop?

Comment: the operating system is windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$InvalidCredentialsException: Invalid credentials at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:586)

You are trying to sync your ZD with your google mail account, do you have 2 factor auth setup?

I just found this, https://bugzilla.zimbra.com/show_bug.cgi?id=79778. Solution was to generate an application-specific password for my google account and use that.  This way, ZD does not need to know how to handle the two-factor login protocol.